# JavaScript: Add event listener on parent popup window

Tags: javascript, popup

i'm currently trying to add an event listener on a popup window that is opened in a parent page.

Let me give you a little bit more explanation: There is a button in an iframe. When this button is clicked an popup window is opened in the parent page that is calling/holding the iframe.

Here is my code:

```
parent.window.open(url, "MyParentWindowPopUp", "width=1000, height=800");
```

With this line of code i open the popup window in the parent page.

When the windows is opened i have to create a listener on it so here is what i use when i add a listener for NON-parent window:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('message', <?php echo $_htmlId; ?>_receive_message, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onmessage', <?php echo $_htmlId; ?>_receive_message);
}
```

How can i transform this code to work for the parent popup window?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can store the reference to the opened Window

```
var popupWindow = parent.window.open(url, "MyParentWindowPopUp", "width=1000, height=800");

if (popupWindow.addEventListener) {
    popupWindow.addEventListener('message', <?php echo $_htmlId; ?>_receive_message, false);
} else if (popupWindow.attachEvent) {
    popupWindow.attachEvent('onmessage', <?php echo $_htmlId; ?>_receive_message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var popup = parent.window.open(/**/);
popup.addEventListener("message", function () {
    console.log("popup window received message");
});
popup.postMessage("foo");
```

`.open` gives you a reference to the window.